# Will a PS4 that supports 220 to 240 volts work in North America?

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4 (Middle East version) and it is written on it that it supports voltage from 220V to 240V. Will it work in Canada and North America, seeing as electricity there is 110v?

Comment: Are you sure 220-240 is actually written on PS4 and not on the power cable?

Comment: You'd probably get more professional answers from electronics.se.

Answer (score 2):

### It *should* be ok.

You can check by looking for the Voltage specs on your PS4. It might be somewhere on the bottom, and you're looking for "Input voltage". For the most part, devices have a range of functional input. Outside of this, it will either not perform to it's proper standard (below the Input range) or cause damage (above the input range).

It should look like this:

[image: PS4 Voltage Information]

This means that the voltage of 110V will work fine with your PS4.

**EDIT:** Since you've stated that your PS4 *says* the voltage range is 220-240V, this conflicts with the [standard tech specs](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/explore/ps4/tech-specs/) for the PS4. I would suggest taking it into an Electronics store to get the voltage tested. However, as I have previously stated, plugging it into the wall will not cause any damage to your PS4, it will simply not function to it's full capacity.

Comment: also this : https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/explore/ps4/tech-specs/

Comment: Yes I’ve checked and as I mentioned before its ranged from 220v to 240v

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMH Oh right, I misread that. That is very odd! I would potentially advise you take it in to a gaming store or any electrics store to get the voltage checked then. That really is odd!